# Inconsistent Differential Equation Result

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing a review problem right now that has gotten me to the equation (which I know to be correct):

$\frac{1}{s}ds = -\frac{1}{200}dt$

Which I then use to solve for $s$. My method is as follows:

$\int \frac{1}{s}ds = \int -\frac{1}{200}dt$

$\int \frac{1}{s}ds =  -\frac{1}{200} \int dt$

$ln(s) = \frac{-t}{200} + C$

$ln(s) =C - \frac{t}{200}$

$e^{ln(s)} = e^{(C - \frac{t}{200})}$

$s = e^{(C - \frac{t}{200})}$

These are all what I'd consider to be fairly straightforward operations...except that I'm going wrong somewhere, because the correct result should actually be:

$s =C e^{(-\frac{t}{200})}$

But I can't for the life of me figure out what step I'm getting incorrect. Is anyone else able to spot it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that

$$e^{\left(C-\frac{t}{200}\right)}=e^C\cdot e^{-\frac{t}{200}}=\widetilde{C} e^{-\frac{t}{200}}$$

Comment: I think you're trying to  say that the two are actually equivalent?

Comment: Exactly! ${}{}$

Comment: There is a tiny difference: The OP' solution results in a $\widetilde{C}$ that is always positive, while in reality the $\widetilde{C}$ can be negative as well. The reason is that $\int \frac{1}{s}ds=\ln(|s|)$ for all $s \neq 0$.